# java function primitive passed by reference

Tags: java, function, reference, primitive

I encountered this problem several times, so I m asking here what is the best practice

I have process that goes true several objects, modifies them  and rises some flags.

```
    boolean erros = false;
    for(MyData data: allData){
    //...

        //@ToDo  move this to a function titleCheck()
        if(data.getTitle().isEmpty()){
            data.setTitle('none');
            erros = true;
        }

        if(data.getTitle().equals('BIG')){
            data.setTitle('small')
        }

        if(data.getTitle().equals('error')){
            errors = true;
        }

    //...
    }
```

I need a function to update the data and change one or more flags
so the preferred syntax is something like this:

```
MyData updatedData = titleCheck(MyData data, &erros){...}
```

but booleans cant be passed by reference so they was it works is:

```
boolean errors = titleCheck(MyData dataForUpdate){...}
```

Witch is way less intuitive .. (at least for me ... coming from PHP background)
The problem gets bigger if you have several flags to update.

So .. what is the proper Java way to handle such structure.

Comment: *Nothing* is passed by reference in Java.

Comment: In java everything is passed by value

Comment: The "proper" Java way to handle it would generally be your second example (the one you refer to as less intuitive). There are other things you could do, such as place your data and your boolean in a container object and pass them both in together, but I don't think that'll read much better. In many ways, this is the price of using different languages, you simply can't always do things exactly the way you're used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
titleCheck(MyData data);
```

given your code above, you're actually changing the data object - *not* a copy of this. Hence you can return the success/failure boolean and you don't have to return the passed object. So now you can OR these values together.

```
boolean error = false;
error |= titleCheck(...);
error |= nameCheck(...);
```

etc.

If you want to pass the object and a status back, you can trivially declare a return class thus:

```
class ReturnResult {
   public boolean error;
   public MyData data;
}
```

(I've made the fields public since I'm using it as a simple structure). The advantage of this approach is that you're making use of OO to tie together related objects, and you can put methods on the above class to make it easy to merge successive results.

Finally I note that you're calling lots of methods on the `MyData` object and determining success/failure outside that object. I would rather put this *within* the `MyData` object. Then the MyData object can store its own valid/invalid state and you can ask it for its own state via an `isValid()` method or similar. This seems like a very OO method of doing things here.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support pass by reference.  Even references are passed by value.

To do what you suggest you need to pass a reference to an object such as `boolean[]` or `AtomicBoolean` and use that instead.